# Shapes not resizing with x-axis behaviour when zooming

Tags: d3.js

I'm stuck getting this to zoom properly: http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/TDz8k/  Pan works okay but the shape size doesn't update on zoom in/out hence it grows in duration.  Any ideas?

```
 var applyZoom = function() {
        // Re-apply the zoom behavior.
        zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
         .x(xRange)
        //.y(y)
         .on("zoom", function() { update() });
         vis.call(zoom);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just move

```
    group.selectAll(".rectband")
         .attr("width", function (d) { return xRange(new Date(d.end)) - xRange(new Date(d.start)) })
         .attr("height", 18)
         .attr("rx", 10)
         .attr("ry", 10)
         .style("opacity", .5) // set the element opacity
         .style("stroke", "black"); // set the line colour;
```

Inside the update function, and call update() as you initialize your graph